# how to extend a silverlight built-in control?

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to create a control that derives from DataGrid. But I couldn't do it. I'm sure I'm missing something but couldn't figure out what? The idea is to move all the datagrid related logic within this control, so the MainPage code would be less.

```
namespace SilverlightClient.Controls
{
    public partial class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        public MyDataGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
Partial declarations of 'SilverlightClient.Controls.MyDataGrid' must not specify different base classes

Answer (score 0):

You have a XAML file for that class that inherits `UserControl`.
Change the root tag in the XAML file to `<DataGrid ...>`.

Comment: I did that, it throws error

The tag 'DataGrid' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
The type 'DataGrid' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

I tried removing those references with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct reference in your XAML: System.Windows.Controls.Data and use that reference to define the control.

```
<data:DataGrid x:Class="...
 ...
 xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
 ...
 >
```